# How do I merge 2 rows into 1 row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, row

```
ReportDateTime   EuId1 EuId2
2020-02-01 1:00  1576  Null    
2020-02-01 1:00  Null  1579    
2020-02-01 2:00  Null  1573    
2020-02-01 2:00  1566  Null
```

This is what I have and this is what I want...

```
 ReportDateTime   EuId1 EuId2    
 2020-02-01 1:00  1576  1579    
 2020-02-01 2:00  1566  1573
```

Here is my code...

```
;WITH cteEq AS (
    SELECT e.EntHID, e.EntCode, e.EntName 
    FROM cfEntity fac (NOLOCK)
    JOIN cfEntityRelation er (NOLOCK) ON fac.EntHID = er.EntParentHID AND er.EntRelEffEnd = '12/31/2078'
    JOIN cfEntity e (NOLOCK) ON er.EntChildHID = e.EntHID AND e.EntTypeTID = -200020
    WHERE e.EntHID IN (SELECT ea.EaHID FROM cfEntityAttribute ea (NOLOCK) WHERE ea.EaKey = 'AirPermitXref_Diesel')
)
SELECT
    ReportDateTime = a.EqReportDate
    , EuId1 = CASE
       WHEN EntName LIKE '%EU1%' THEN a.EqPwr
       END
    , EuId2 = CASE
       WHEN EntName LIKE '%EU2%' THEN a.EqPwr
       END
FROM eqHourlyAir a (NOLOCK)
JOIN cteEq e (NOLOCK) ON a.EqHID = e.EntHID
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT ad.EqHID, ad.EqReportDate, ad.EqRunTime
    FROM eqHourlyAir ad (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN cfEntityAttribute ea (NOLOCK) ON ad.EqHID = CAST(ea.EaValue AS INT) AND ea.EaKey = 'AirPermitXref_DWI'
    WHERE ea.EaHID = a.EqHID 
    AND ad.EqReportDate = a.EqReportDate
) dwi
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT ad.EqHID, ad.EqReportDate, ad.EqRunTime
    FROM eqHourlyAir ad (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN cfEntityAttribute ea (NOLOCK) ON ad.EqHID = CAST(ea.EaValue AS INT) AND ea.EaKey = 'AirPermitXref_Diesel'
    WHERE ea.EaHID = a.EqHID 
    AND ad.EqReportDate = a.EqReportDate
) dsl
WHERE CAST(a.EqReportDate AS DATE) >= @StartDate AND CAST(a.EqReportDate AS DATE) <= @EndDate 
ORDER BY a.EqReportDate
```

Comment: Why are you spamming `NOLOCK`, you ***do*** understand what it does and the severe implications it has, right? If you *really* need to query hint against every table (top tip, you don't) then you should be setting the isolation level at the start, dumping `NOLOCK` everywhere.

Comment: Please share complete sample data for better understanding and please explain what difficulties you are facing with this code.

Comment: Please, provide [**minimal, reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Parsing the query by someone's eyes is a waste of time, so post `create` and `insert` statements to create a setup for answer.

Comment: If you MUST use nolock, understand the consequences, and are prepared to deal with errors or incorrect data, then AT LEAST use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Comment: Required Reading: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Also, a pet peeve, [the semicolon (`;`) is a statement terminator](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-the-semicolon-is-a-statement-terminator/) *not* a "beginningator". It goes at the  *end* of **all** your statements, not at the start of statements that required the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Answer (score 1):

1. using nolock hint is not the best idea !
2. if you have one null value and only one non value for each reportingdate you can grooup by ReportDateTime and get the max value :

```
...
SELECT
    ReportDateTime = a.EqReportDate,
    EuId1 = MAX(CASE WHEN EntName LIKE '%EU1%' THEN a.EqPwr END),
    EuId2 = MAX(CASE WHEN EntName LIKE '%EU2%' THEN a.EqPwr END)
FROM
 {...}
WHERE
    CAST(a.EqReportDate AS DATE) >= @StartDate
    AND CAST(a.EqReportDate AS DATE) <= @EndDate
GROUP BY a.EqReportDate
ORDER BY
    a.EqReportDate
```

Answer (score 0):

From you sample data it's very easy to select your desired result as below:

```
select ReportDateTime  ,max(EuId1) EuId1,max(EuId2) EuId2 from 
(select * from table1 join table2 on .... )t
group by ReportDateTime
```

But your query indicates that there is more to the story. Please share some more information.